# Why my tmux session dies after ec2stop?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EBS-backed EC2 instance. According to docs, it should be 'paused' if I stop (ec2stop) it. However, I noticed that server is indeed restarted after I start the instance back. Uptime counts from 0 after start, and tmux session is detached.

For comparison, everything above mentioned is really paused when I 'savestate' VirtualBox machine, so I can attach to existing tmux session after starting VBox machine back.

Could you please explain what is the difference? What really happens when I stop the EC2 instance?

Thanks,
Robusta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I entered your question into Google.
The first hits contained the answer to your question:

- [AWS FAQ](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html#instance_stop)
- [RightScale FAQ](http://support.rightscale.com/index.php?title=06-FAQs/FAQ_0149_-_What%27s_the_difference_between_Terminating_and_Stopping_an_EC2_Instance%3F)

Amazon says:

> [...]The instance performs a **normal shutdown** and stops running (the
>   status goes to stopping and then stopped).[...]

Comment: That link doesn't work (at least for me): it brings me to their home page. Perhaps one has to be logged into their site ?

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why I was not able to extract this info. I was looking for a way to really pause (not shutdown) an instance, so I was a bit biased...